# Move files from sepecific subdirectories to another based on names in Python

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, shutil

Given a directory `./` and its subdirectories `('project1, project2, project3, ...')` and files structure as follows:

```
├── project1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── process
│   │   └── f1
│   │       ├── pic1.png
│   │       └── pic2.jpg
│   ├── progress
│   │   └── f2
│   │       ├── 623.jpg
│   │       └── pic2323.png
│   └── session
│       └── f3
│           ├── 5632116.jpg
│           └── 72163.png
└── project2
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── process
    │   └── f1
    │       ├── pic1.png
    │       └── pic2.jpg
    ├── progress
    │   └── f2
    │       ├── 623.jpg
    │       └── pic2323.png
    └── session
        └── f3
            ├── 5632116.jpg
            └── 72163.png
```

For each `project` folder, I need to move pictures from `process` to empty `files1`, from `progress` and `session` to empty `files2`.

The expected result will like this:

```
|── project1
|   ├── file1
|   │     ├── pic1.png
|   │     └── pic2.jpg
|   |── file2
|         ├── 623.jpg
|         └── pic2323.png
|         ├── 5632116.jpg
|         └── 72163.png
└── project2
    ├── file1
    │     ├── pic1.png
    │     └── pic2.jpg
    |── file2
          ├── 623.jpg
          └── pic2323.png
          ├── 5632116.jpg
          └── 72163.png
```

My trial code works, but I don't think it's concise enough, welcome to improve it:

```
base_dir = './'
src_dst_map = {
   'session': 'files1',
   'process': 'files2',
   'progress': 'files2'
}

for child in os.listdir(base_dir):
    # print(child)
    child_path = os.path.join(base_dir, child)
    # print(child_path)
    # src_path = os.path.join(child_path, 'session')
    # print(src_path)
    for src, dst in src_dst_map.items():
        # print(src)
        src_path = os.path.join(child_path, src)
        dst_path = os.path.join(child_path, dst)
        print(src_path)
        print(dst_path)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_path):
            # print(root)
            for file in files:
                # print(file)
                srce_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                print(srce_path)
                shutil.move(srce_path, dst_path)
        shutil.rmtree(src_path, ignore_errors = True)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve? Should it be more generally usable, or easier to read, or are you looking for ways to reduce lines of code?

Comment: To reduce lines of code if possible, I think my code is not concise enough.

Comment: If I want to move also duplicated names images into `dst_path`, save both of them, how could I do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this is already quite concise and it does the job, so I would not bother too much about changing it. Your code runs in 10 lines (plus set up of the dictionary and base path).

Regarding the duplicated images, you could check for existance of `file` in `dst_path`, and if it is present, add a prefix (or suffix) to the dublicated file.

In the following, the prefix according to the source is added, until a unique file name is found. This also catches, if there are more than one dublicate of the same file in one subfolder. You could change this according to your specific needs, but it should give you the general idea.

```
...

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_path):
        for file in files:
            srce_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            while os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dst_path, file)):
                file = '_'.join([src, file])
            shutil.move(srce_path, os.path.join(dst_path, file))
```

I opted for a prefix, as this is much simpler to implement. A suffix would have to be added between the filename and the file ending, this would require a bit of additional code.